# Number theory - prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

Prove that 
If $p$ is prime s.t. $0 \lt n \le p$ , then $p \vert \binom{p}{n}$
I know that if $p \vert q$, then $q = kp$, for some integer number $k$ . But I don’t know how to prove that $p$ divided like above

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Do you mean $p|\binom{n}{p}$? That admits the counterexample $n=p+1$.

Comment: Is this supposed to say that $p$ divides ${n!\over (n-p)!p!}?$  That isn't true.  What if $n=8,p=7?$

Comment: Well, that obviously is not true if $p > \frac n2$.

Comment: For all prime $p$ and all natural $k$ what you say is equivalent to  $p$ divides $\dbinom{p+k}{p}$. Try to find a counterexample.

Comment: You’ve completely changed the question with your edit. The original question was $n!/p!(n-p)!$, to which you got three answers. Please open a new question and revert this to the original because it’s unreasonable to expect people to keep up with such a huge change.

Comment: As ${p \choose n} = 0$ if $n > p$ and ${p \choose n} = 1$ if $n = p$ and as $p|0$ and $p \not \mid 1$ the question is trivial for the new question you changed it too.

Answer (score 0):

By [Lucas's Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lucas%27_Theorem) (which you can easily reprove for $k=p$),

$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv\binom{\lfloor{n/p}\rfloor}{1}\binom{n\pmod p}{0}\pmod{p}\equiv \lfloor n/p\rfloor \pmod{p}.$$

It follows that $p|\binom{n}{p}$ iff $p|\lfloor n/p\rfloor$. Otherwise it's not true.

Comment: P is above and n is down and p greater than n ، thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_p(n)$ be the sum of digits of $n$ when written in base $p$, $k = v_p(n)$ be the highest integer such that $p^k|n$, we can find $v_p\left(\binom{n}{p}\right)$ from this identity:
$$v_p\left(\binom{n}{p}\right)=s_p(n-p) + s_p(p) - s_p(n) = s_p(n-p) + 1 - s_p(n)$$
So if you have special properties of $n,p$ then you can even compute $v_p\left(\binom{n}{p}\right)$. As you can see, we cannot always choose $n$ such that $s_p(n-p)+1>s_p(n)$. If the second digit from right to left in base $p$ representation is non-zero, then $s_p(n-p) = s_p(n)-1$, thus we have to choose $n$ such that $[n/p]\equiv 0 (mod p)$

Comment: P is above and n is down and p greater than n ، thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

${n \choose p} = \frac {n!}{(n-p)!p!} = \frac {\prod\limits_{j= n- p + 1}^n j}{p!}$ is an integer.

The numerator is a product of $n- p + 1, n-p+2,...... , n$ which are $p$ terms.  So exactly on of the terms is divisible by $p$ and the rest are not.  Assume the term that is divisible by $p$ is $M$.  Likewise the denominator is a product of $1,2,3,....,p$ terms only only of which one term, $p$, is divisible by $p$.

So ${n \choose p} = \frac {\prod\limits_{j= n- p + 1}^n j}{p!}= \frac {(\prod\limits_{j = n - p +1; j \ne M}^n j) \times M}{(p-1)!\times p} = \frac {\prod\limits_{j = n - p +1; j \ne M}^n j }{(p-1)!}\times \frac M p$.

Now none of the $n-p+1, n-p+2,.....,M-1, M+1, ....n$ are divisible by $p$ so $p$ does not divide $\frac {\prod\limits_{j = n - p +1; j \ne M}^n j }{(p-1)!}$[1].

So $p|{n \choose p}$ if and only if $p|\frac Mp$.  Which can only happen if $p^2|M$.

So this statement is true if $n-p+1, .... ,n$ will contain a multiple of $p^2$ but will not be true of it does not.

So for example $13| {174 \choose 13}$ because $13^2|169$.  But $13 \not \mid {187 \choose 13}$ because $13^2\not \mid 182$.

.....

[1] Note, that $p$ is prime is a necessary requirement.  If $p$ were noot prime then some of those terms could be divisible by *factors* of $p$ and thus $p$ could divide the product.  But as $p$ is prime that is not possible.

Comment: " Be careful. P is above and n is down".  I don't think so.  $n > p$ and ${n \choose p} = \frac {n!}{p! (n-p)!}$.  And $n! = 1*2*..... *n = (1*2*.....*(n-p))*((n-p +1)(n-p+2)*.....*n) = (n-p)!*\prod\limits_{k=n-p+1}^n k$.  So ${n \choose p} = \frac {n!}{p! (n-p)!}=\frac { (n-p)!*\prod\limits_{k=n-p+1}^n k}{p!(n-p)!} = \frac {\prod\limits_{k=n-p+1}^n k}{p!}$.

Comment: If "$p$ is up and n is down" then if $p < n$ then ${p\choose n} = 0$ and $p|0$ because all numbers divide $0$.  If $p = n$ then ${p\choose n} = 1$ and $p \not \mid {p \choose n}$.

Comment: And you can't just *change* a question after three people answer and warn the people who answered the *original* question correctly to "be careful".

Comment: P is above and n is down and p greater than n

Comment: Thanks alot and sorry for the mistake